# Read MSDTC configuration

Tags: c#, configuration, msdtc

Does anyone have any ideas on how to read the MSDTC configuration on the current machine? I am specifically trying to check that the user has performed the following steps:

1. Open Component Management (Start > All Programs > Administrative Tools > Component Services)
2. Double-click on Component Services, then expand Computers. Right-click on My Computer 
   and select Properties
3. On the MSDTC tab, click the Security Configuration button, and configure the properties as follows:
4. Network DTC Access: Checked
5. Allow Remote Clients: Checked
6. Allow Inbound: Checked
7. Allow Outbound: Checked
8. Incoming Caller Authentication Required: Selected

It's part of a small component I need to write to validate end-user configuration. I don't think I would attempt to fix it if it were wrong: just point the user at the help file - so only read only is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do this programmatically from any API, or WMI.
At least you can check the registry information at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC\Security
```

Comment: This is absolutely the WRONG way to go, as it is an *implementation* detail not a defined contract (unlike the COM interfaces).

Comment: I would normally fully agree to not accessing the registry for such information. However, at least now, the registry keys are [documented properly](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753620(v=ws.10).aspx) by Microsoft. So it is probably OK.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the COM+ Administration classes/interfaces to do this.  It will require COM interop though on your part.

The reference is located at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681189(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I decided to use the easier route of the registry - I only need read access. Upvote.

Comment: @casperOne
I have used the COM+ administration classes a lot over the years. I may just be blind, but with which classes can I control the MSDTC settings?